# Is it a bad decision to introduce a method only for exception throwing?

Tags: java, exception

i currenty thinking about a concept which should treat illegal states in my java program. 
I have introduced a class which does processing steps on images.

```
public class ImageProcessor{
    public Image processImage(Image img){
       //do some processing steps
    }
}
```

Now, I want to introduce another class which should check the the image before doing the processing.

```
public class ImageChecker{
     public void checkImage(Image img) throws ImageNotProcessableException{
         //for example, if the image has a width of 0 the full process
         //should be broken, throw an exception
         if (img.width=0) throw new ImageNotProcessableException("width is 0");

         //other conditions throwing also exceptions

         // the image is fine, do nothing
     }
}
```

The two classes should be used in a Coordinator class.

```
 public class Coordinator{
    public void coordinate(Image img) throws ImageNotProcessableException{
       //initialize both

       imageChecker.checkImage(img); //if no exception is throw the process can run
       imageprocessor.processImage(img);
    }
 }
```

The question is now, is this way of treating Exception (defining a separate method for them) a bad coding style? The idea for this design was to prevent polluting processing code with exception handling. I want the coordinator to throw exceptions and I thought this could be a senseful way. What do you think, is this a good way or is it an antipattern.
Thanks!

Comment: Is `imageChecker` really a separate class that will be useful to multiple other classes, or are the checks it performs actually specific to `imageProcessor`? And how many methods does `imageChecker` have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The validating method itself is a very good idea. You introduce very good separation of concerns - checking preconditions and validation in one place and actual processing in another.

However the usage is incorrect. The `ImageProcessor` should eagerly call `ImageChecker.checkImage()`. Otherwise the client of your library might forget to call it and pass invalid image.

Also *@Damien_The_Unbeliever* brings up a very good point about the structure of the code.

To make it as fancy as possible I would create an `ImageProcessor` interface with two implementations: one that performs the actual processing and a [*decorator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) implementation (`ImageChecker`) that performs validation and passes validated object to target `ImageProcessor`.

This way you can either use safe or fast (assuming validation is costly) implementation. Also in the future you might introduce other elements to the [chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) like caching or profiling.

Comment: I was in the process of writing almost the exact same response!

Comment: This was exactly my intention. I want to separate the concerns. If I had used Aspects I would have done this with an aspect. What you mentioned refering to call ImageChecker in ImageProcessor, my Intention was to completely decouple the both classes and join their functionalities in the Coordinator. I want to provide the Coordinator to other clients.

Answer (score 1):

This is not unreasonable.  Although if `checkImage` exists for the sole purpose of checking whether it's ok to process an image and has no other return type, it would be reasonable to have it return a status code/object rather than throwing an Exception and returning void, e.g.,

```
ImageStatus status = checkImage(image);
if (status.isOk()) { 
  processImage(image);
}
```

This would be analogous to checking for divide by zero:

```
if (y != 0) {
  z = x / y;
}
```

Checked exceptions generally are better for situations where you can't confirm a priori whether something will succeed or fail until you try it, e.g., IOException.

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 questions here, and it's useful to separate them.

1. Should the caller see a class called "ImageProcessor", or a class called "Coordinator"?
2. Is it good to do validation of inputs in a separate method from the main processing?
3. Should this code use checked exceptions or unchecked exceptions?

My answers would be:

1. Use the prettier name for the classes or interfaces you are exposing.  So, here "ImageProcessor" is much nicer than "Coordinator".  ("Coordinator" sounds like an implementation detail you don't want to expose.)
2. This is an implementation decision.  It's fine to separate some validation logic into a separate method if it makes things cleaner.  But, you need to be careful of falling into a trap of thinking it is possible to anticipate upfront everything that can possibly go wrong in later stages of processing.  The method that does the actual processing still needs to be free to throw exceptions so it can describe failures as accurately as possible, no matter what the initial quick validation decided.  Also, you want to avoid writing the validation code in two places, since that is unnecessary code duplication.  So, I'm a bit skeptical about having this separation, but I'd need to see the code.  More likely, it's better to separate the actual image processing itself into various sub-tasks, and do the validation at the point you need it.
3. This is the age-old Java checked exceptions debate that will not go away in our lifetimes, and is impossible to summarize here.  But, I think the consensus has fairly strongly shifted to favor using runtime exception rather than checked exception.  Of course, legacy APIs still use checked exceptions.  But for most new code, it's better to use runtime exceptions rather than checked exceptions, since this allows more robust code.  (Checked exceptions have the annoying property of often being wrapped, rewrapped, swallowed, or otherwise mangled before they can get to the exception handler, and they cause lots of collateral damage along the way by making everyone's throws clause get longer.)